# Creating Dupe records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

**Background**: We are in process of migrating our ETL from an old database to a new database which record data differently. In order to be as close to our old system (which creates 1 record for sale and another if the sale was cancelled and the NEW system creating only the cancelled record), I need to create another record for these sales so that I match 1:1 between the old and new database.

What would be an effective way to achieve this. For example, I can get 10k records that need duplication. These are based on specific conditions in the database.

Here is the sample of data :

```
AcctNum           CancelFlag             SaleDate          SalePrice         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                    Y                 2022-06-27        100.00
  2                    Y                 2022-05-10        156.00
```

Desired output:

```
AcctNum            CancelFlag             SaleDate          SalePrice
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                    Y                  2022-06-27         100.00
  1                                       2022-06-27        -100.00
  2                    Y                  2022-05-10         156.00
  2                                       2022-05-10        -156.00
```

Please note that on the duped row, I won't have the CancelFlag = Y and the SalePrice will be flipped to a negative sign to indicate the cancellation of the sale.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you basically want to create new rows for each of those rows selected , with the `CheckFlag` off, and the amount negated - right?

So try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (AcctNum, CancelFlag, SaleDate, SalePrice)
    SELECT
        AcctNum, NULL, SaleDate, SalePrice * -1.0
    FROM
        dbo.YourTable
    WHERE
        CancelFlag = 'Y'
        AND SalePrice > 0.0;
```

Does that do what you're looking for? You might need to tweak your `WHERE` clause to get precisely those existing rows from the table that you're really interested in.

Comment: Thats a great idea actually. This will work well because the number of rows is limited. I know how I want to get my 10k records that match the criteria, but I was just confused on how best to create the new rows with the flipped sign and the flag being null. Thanks Marc!